# Language switcher menu

Tags: gui-design, menu

I want to design Language selection menu and the requirement is,

on the right side menu should appear (which shows the selected language)

on selection, it should list all the languages available 
and also the selected language should be shown as selected

screenshot is attached and we use bootstrap.

This might be simple but I'm new to design so any help will be highly appreciated

Thanks,
Prakash.[image]

Comment: What is the question/problem?

Comment: how to create a menu for language selection, like the attached screenshot ?

Comment: Are you asking how to build it or how to design it? (It looks like you already have a design)

Comment: I want to design it

Comment: Ah, so the image is just an example of what you want. You shouldn't ask how to design something, that is just too broad for this site. But you can ask how to solve more specific problems. Let's start with the example: What should change in that design so that it suits your situation? If you are more interested in the aesthetics of the design you can try to ask a question on [graphicdesign.stackexchange.com](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Thank you! for your directions.

Comment: It might be a bad idea to use flags for languages, "the Arabic language, for example, is used in many countries and cannot be identified with one particular flag" (source, and more ideas at https://uxdesign.cc/my-take-on-language-selectors-945caceb58f7 )

Comment: Using flags are fine if they are ment to indicate a regional dialect. However, do not use the wrong flag when doing this. Both US and UK show an Indian flag. That will definately confuse people.

Comment: I had a related (not the same though) question in the past, maybe helpful: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/37017/language-of-language-names-in-the-language-selector

Answer (score 1):

Booking.com example is a good way to approach this problem. I would maybe drop the flag, because flags represent countries, not languages, and duplicate language name in current UI language e.g.

[LV] Latvian - Latviski for English UI and

[LV] Latviski - Latvian for Latvian UI

Answer (score 0):

Couple of points from my point of view;

- Makes no sense to have "Most often used by people in India". User has come here to select language, he is clear what to select
- With so much langauges, placing real-time search bar on top (when you type, matching results are left on list) - could be a good idea
- You can think of doing some IP recognition for the website. And detect location based on IP and then serve option with fewer languages
- You should have X option to close pop up, it is not seeable in your screenshot

Comment: IP recognition: depends what's the website, e.g. travel website: user access it from the destination, might not be fluent in the local language.

Answer (score 0):

I would drop the flag and add the first three letters of each language which seems an unequivocal sign of the selected language.